How to parse XML in Google Sheet?
This URL
https://export.arxiv.org/api/query?id_list=2308.05734 contains the xml below.
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<feed xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
  <link href="http://arxiv.org/api/query?search_query%3D%26id_list%3D2308.05734%26start%3D0%26max_results%3D10" rel="self" type="application/atom+xml"/>
  <title type="html">ArXiv Query: search_query=&amp;id_list=2308.05734&amp;start=0&amp;max_results=10</title>
  <id>http://arxiv.org/api/u+tTdcCSDRLdpBnNrSZIkcgVUsg</id>
  <updated>2024-06-24T00:00:00-04:00</updated>
  <opensearch:totalResults xmlns:opensearch="http://a9.com/-/spec/opensearch/1.1/">1</opensearch:totalResults>
  <opensearch:startIndex xmlns:opensearch="http://a9.com/-/spec/opensearch/1.1/">0</opensearch:startIndex>
  <opensearch:itemsPerPage xmlns:opensearch="http://a9.com/-/spec/opensearch/1.1/">10</opensearch:itemsPerPage>
  <entry>
    <id>http://arxiv.org/abs/2308.05734v3</id>
    <updated>2024-05-11T11:24:51Z</updated>
    <published>2023-08-10T17:55:13Z</published>
    <title>AudioLDM 2: Learning Holistic Audio Generation with Self-supervised
  Pretraining</title>
    <summary>  Although audio generation shares commonalities across different types of
...
</summary>
    <author>
      <name>Haohe Liu</name>
    </author>
    <author>
      <name>Yi Yuan</name>
    </author>
   
    <arxiv:comment xmlns:arxiv="http://arxiv.org/schemas/atom">Accepted by IEEE/ACM Transactions on Audio, Speech and Language
  Processing. Project page is https://audioldm.github.io/audioldm2</arxiv:comment>
    <link href="http://arxiv.org/abs/2308.05734v3" rel="alternate" type="text/html"/>
    <link title="pdf" href="http://arxiv.org/pdf/2308.05734v3" rel="related" type="application/pdf"/>
    <arxiv:primary_category xmlns:arxiv="http://arxiv.org/schemas/atom" term="cs.SD" scheme="http://arxiv.org/schemas/atom"/>
    <category term="cs.SD" scheme="http://arxiv.org/schemas/atom"/>
    <category term="cs.AI" scheme="http://arxiv.org/schemas/atom"/>
    <category term="cs.MM" scheme="http://arxiv.org/schemas/atom"/>
    <category term="eess.AS" scheme="http://arxiv.org/schemas/atom"/>
    <category term="eess.SP" scheme="http://arxiv.org/schemas/atom"/>
  </entry>
</feed>

How to extract the Authors, title and publication date ?
I tried:
=IMPORTXML("http://export.arxiv.org/api/query?id_list=2308.05734", "//title")
=IMPORTXML("http://export.arxiv.org/api/query?id_list=2308.05734", "//published")
=JOIN(", ", IMPORTXML("http://export.arxiv.org/api/query?id_list=2308.05734", "//author/name"))

But none of them work. I get "Imported content is empty."
However, when I do =IMPORTXML("http://export.arxiv.org/api/query?id_list=2308.05734", "/")
I get all raw values.

I've removed the Excel tag. Excel and Google Sheets are two distinctly different products, with different functionality and capabilities. If you're asking about Google Sheets, you're clearly not asking about Excel.

How about the following formulas?

Authors
=IMPORTXML("https://export.arxiv.org/api/query?id_list=2308.05734", "//*[local-name()='author']")


title
=IMPORTXML("https://export.arxiv.org/api/query?id_list=2308.05734", "//*[local-name()='title']")


publication date
=IMPORTXML("https://export.arxiv.org/api/query?id_list=2308.05734", "//*[local-name()='published']")



Reference:

local-name


Do you by chance know why my attempt does not work ? I followed the example in the https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_syntax.asp

@TSR Thank you for replying. About Do you by chance know why my attempt does not work ?, when I tested your XPath with your provided URL, I confirmed the same situation. When I saw the XML data from the URL, I thought that for example, when the title is retrieved, /feed/title can be used. But, it returns empty. So, in order not to ignore the namespace, I used *[local-name()='###']. This indicates that all namespaces are matched. I guessed that this might be able to be used. If this explanation was not useful, I apologize.
